# Creating a Video montage from selected pictures from gallery

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I wanted to know if there is any way using react native, we can create a  video montage. User selects few photos from gallery. The video montage should be created for these selected photos. I am require to do this without ffmpeg. Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: Have you googled this?  Your question is broad and shows zero research effort.

Comment: Yeah I tried googling. But I am not getting any helpful way of doing this. I am sorry if my question seems broad. What I am looking for is, say if I have 5 different images somewhere in my gallery or my project folder, I want to create a video of these 5 images. As an example, a video that is created by facebook showing last year data or our friendanniversary, where it picks the photos/images from our profile, and generates a video.

Answer (score 0):

For the few images selection part - maybe [this](http://%20https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-upload-multiple-images) package could be useful.And as for the sound for the video part, maybe [this module](http://react-native-sound) is worth a try.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. Actually, I already have images. What I need to do is, say I have selected 5 images. I want to create a video of these 5 images i.e. these 5 images will be shown as part of video and not image. React-native-sound package, seems to add sound to existing video and not create new video with the given set of images. As an example, a video that is created by facebook showing last year data or our friendanniversary, where it picks the photos/images from our profile, and generates a video